# Swift - How do I check if switch case contains an value

Tags: switch-statement, swift5

I'm trying to do something like that

```swift
var name = "Thiago Valente"

switch name {
case .contains("Valente"):
   return "Hello, My surname is like your"
default:
   return "Hi ;)"
}
```

The `contains` don't exists, so it is possible to do with **switch case**? ( I know it's simple to do with if-else )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `let x` pattern, followed by a `where` clause:

```
var name = "Thiago Valente"

switch name {
case let x where x.contains("Valente"):
   return "Hello, My surname is like your"
default:
   return "Hi ;)"
}
```

Normally `let x` will match every value, but you say more specifically what kind of values you want to match in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If value is optional just add ?

```
var name: String? = "Thiago Valente"

switch name {
case let x? where x.contains("Valente"):
   return "Hello, My surname is like your"
default:
   return "Hi ;)"
}
```